# Matrix addition using decltype and templates in C++ 11

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, auto, decltype

In the fourth edition of The C++ programming Language, Dr. Stroustrup uses an example to calculate the result of two matrices to demonstrate decltype() specifier. The question I have is the relation between the arrow operator -> after the parenthesis in the first part. is the result of the declaration a reference in this code? (the part that begins with auto operator+(const ...)

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<U>& b)-> Matrix<decltype(T{}+U{})>
{
  Matrix<decltype(T{}+U{})> rest;
  for (int i=0; i!=a.rows(); ++i)
       for (int j=0; j!=a.cols(); ++j)
            res(i,j) += a(i,j) + b(i,j);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: The term for further research is "trailing return type". In this case, it's not even necessary - the example could just as well be written using "normal" return type, as `Matrix<decltype(T{}+U{})> operator+(const Matrix<T>& a, const Matrix<U>& b)`

Comment: spot on. thank you